# How to make doctrine create a table without having an entity in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, session, doctrine-orm, doctrine

To be able to scale and keep things easy, i want to store sessions in a postgres database. The schema is managed by doctrine and i created a table 'session' to hold the session manually (like in the [symfony tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html)).

Problem is: When using doctrine:migrations:diff it keeps generating sql to delete this table. So how can i tell doctrine, that i want this session-table without having to create an entity for it?

Comment: I'd create the session entity, if only for sake of reference.  You don't need to actually use it.

Comment: I don't understand why this is "closed as too broad". It is very specific, it could even be more general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need tell Doctrine to ignore that table: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#manual-tables